# XTR Double chain set to single?

Tags: mountain-bike, xtr

is it possible to convert a m9100 double chainset crank to a single crank? Thanks Matt

Comment: Not sure if it helps but Shimano has a great compatibility chart for components, maybe you can even work it out from [there](https://productinfo.shimano.com/#/com?cid=C-432&acid=C-558). I can't see why it shouldn't work, as long as you have a long-cage (SGS) rear-derailleur, it should fit for both 1x and 2x (RD-Mx120-SGS listed for both applications).

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can: the chainrings are direct mount, you can keep the crank and change the chainring. The exploded view shows that except the chainrings, all the other parts are the same: https://dassets.shimano.com/content/dam/global/cg1SHICCycling/final/ev/ev/EV-FC-M9100-4378B.pdf

But as highlighted in the comment by DoNut, you may need to change the rear derailleur if you want a 10-51 cassette. The RD-Mx120 rear derailleur only works with 10-45 cassettes, the RD-Mx100-GS works with 10-45 cassettes and the RD-Mx100-SGS works with 10-51 ones.